# Reverse regex for mink "the url should match"

Tags: regex, preg-match, behat, mink

how can i reverse a query like this.

```
the url should match ".*window\.open.*"
```

I would have a scenario like...

```
the url should not match ".*window\.open.*"
```

How can i reverse the regexp?

Tried something like

```
".*[^window\.open].*"
"[^(window\.open)].*"
"[^window\.open].*"
```

Nothing works ;(

Comment: Couldnt you just test the match and negate the result? I mean, if the regexp matches, it obviously does not satisfy your second scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of `mink` but you can use **negative look-ahead** if its regex engine supports it.

```
/^(?!.*window\.open).*/
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cN3bM3)

**Note** I would have preferred inverting match rather than inverting regex. Most of the language support inverting feature.